# R: append a new row of growth rate to wide data frame

Tags: r

I am new to R and working with some wide data that looks like:

```
Indicator<-c("C","I","G","NX","GDP")
Y2015<-c(20,20,20,40,100)
Y2016<-c(40,40,40,80,200)
Y2017<-c(60,60,60,120,300)
Y2018<-c(80,80,80,160,400)
df<-data.frame(Indicator,Y2015,Y2016,Y2017,Y2018,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
  Indicator Y2015 Y2016 Y2017 Y2018
1         C    20    40    60    80
2         I    20    40    60    80
3         G    20    40    60    80
4        NX    40    80   120   160
5       GDP   100   200   300   400
```

My question is how I can calculate the growth rates of GDP of each year and then append the results to a new row? The result should look something like:

```
  Indicator Y2015 Y2016 Y2017 Y2018
1         C    20    40    60    80
2         I    20    40    60    80
3         G    20    40    60    80
4        NX    40    80   120   160
5       GDP   100   200   300   400
6         g    NA  100%  100%  100%
```

I found several solutions that work with long data frames but do not seem to solve my problem. Due to size and missing data of the actual data set, I prefer not to switch column variables with row variables and turn it into a long data frame. The actual size of data set to calculate are much larger than the sample. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rbind`

```
rbind(df, list("g", NA, "100%", "100%", "100%"))
#   Indicator Y2015 Y2016 Y2017 Y2018
#1         C    20    40    60    80
#2         I    20    40    60    80
#3         G    20    40    60    80
#4        NX    40    80   120   160
#5       GDP   100   200   300   400
#6         g    NA  100%  100%  100%
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks! Sorry if I was not clear about myself. How can I calculate the growth rates in r and append the results to a new row?

Comment: @Kathleen1412  It is not clear about the logic for calculating it.  If you could show how you got that number, it would be great

Comment: Sure, it is simply df[6.4]<-df[5,4]/df[d[5,3]*100-100, df[6,5]<- df[5,5]/df[5,4]*100-100, etc..